# Create file in Memory, add content and convert to Base64

Tags: memory, abap

There is a Web Service that is running in an external system. The Web Service expects an **XML file which is Base64 encoded**.

In my ABAP program, I have the XML that I want to post to the Web Service in a XSTRING variable.

The issue here is that the Base64 version of a string and a file which contains the the same string is inherently different.

The most direct solution that I know is to write the string to a file and then convert the file into Base64 and post it to the Web Service. The problem here is that the XML string that I have to too sensitive to be stored in the file system even temporarily.

So my question:

Is there a way to create a file during runtime in memory, add the XML that I have into that file in memory and finally convert it to a Base64 string, all during the runtime without ever using the actual file system.

```
DATA: lv_xstring TYPE xstring.
xstring = '<document>some xml data</document>'.
```

xstring --> into a file in memory --> convert to a Base64 string

Comment: What will do in ABAP with stream like variable? May be there are several solution for your problem. You can store all data in xstring look like your example code block or you can use ABAP and SAP Memory.

Comment: "Create a file in memory" doesn't mean anything to me, but maybe you're looking  after stream classes like in other programming languages, i.e. in your case you want to create a procedure to process an input stream of characters, and at run time you can decide to pass an instance of a stream class which can be either a text file stream class, or a string variable stream class, or a database CLOB column stream class, etc.?

Comment: @SandraRossi have added the actual problem that I'm faced with. Hope it makes the issue clearer.

Comment: @mkysoft I'm not clear on what you are trying to say. I've updated the question, hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: why do you need to store it as file at all? convert to base64 and pass to service? what is the problem?

Comment: @Suncatcher the service expects a file with the string inside encoded in Base64. The service is external and I do not have control over it.

Comment: The requirement is completely unclear. Can you please post a HTTP request with a "file inside" (whatever it means) that works for this web service (make sure it works with postman for instance), then we can answer how to do it with ABAP. Thank you. NB: do you mean a multipart HTTP request? OData?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly convert string or xstring to base64 in ABAP. Check SCMS_BASE64_ENCODE_STR FM for xtsring to base64 string conversition.

On the other hand, generally binary data (xstring) transport as base64 encoded string in SOAP body. So may be you don't need to convert it to base64, just convert xml to xstring then assign it to method parameter.

Comment: Base64 is to encode bytes (xstring) into a sequence of characters (string). To encode characters (string) instead of bytes, they must be encoded into bytes, for instance UTF-8 is quite common. What SCMS_BASE64_ENCODE_STR does, is to encode bytes into a string in base 64. So, before that, the input XML must be encoded into UTF-8.

Comment: @SandraRossi @ mkysoft thanks for looking into this, I'm aware of the SCMS_STRING_TO_XSTRING which converts string to XSTRING and SCMS_BASE64_ENCODE_STR which converts it to Unicode. The issue that I have is not with the conversion, but how to create a file stream in memeory, put the XML as it's contents and take it to a string, all without actually writing the file in memory to the file system

Comment: @Isuru, I don't think you need memory system doing this. Where are you get XML in ABAP? Is it ixmldocument object? You can share more sample code for your needs.